# What can we expect in this date range query example?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Refer to the [ElasticSearch example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html), I hardly understand that it has two date ranges(gt/lt and gte/lte) into one query.

Why does it give two date ranges and what could be different when we use gt/lt or gte/lte only?

**Fluent DSL Example**

```
q
.DateRange(c => c
    .Name("named_query")
    .Boost(1.1)
    .Field(p => p.Description)
    .GreaterThan(FixedDate)
    .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored(FixedDate).RoundTo(TimeUnit.Month))
    .LessThan("01/01/2012")
    .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Now)
    .Format("dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy")
    .TimeZone("+01:00")
)
```

**Example json output.**

```
{
  "range": {
    "description": {
      "_name": "named_query",
      "boost": 1.1,
      "format": "dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy",
      "gt": "2015-06-06T12:01:02.123",
      "gte": "2015-06-06T12:01:02.123||/M",
      "lt": "01/01/2012",
      "lte": "now",
      "time_zone": "+01:00"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's just a didactic example, showing that it is possible to add both options. In reality, the query is correct and valid and Elasticsearch will use the outer limits (the `lte` and `gte` bits) and it will "translate" that query into this Lucene one:

```
description:[2015-06-06T12:01:02.123||/M TO now]^1.1
```

Comment: this is correct; the documentation is just a (contrived) example of the available properties on a range query with dates, and the implicit conversions available to pass values as `DateMath`, `DateTime` or `string`

Comment: Thanks all. It would be good to add descriptions to the example.